# Dynamically generating complex data structures in Ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

The way I came up with is:

```yaml
- name: ...
  set_fact:
    _forwards: '{% set _r = [] %}{%
        for _g in _guests %}{{
            _r.append({
                "p_from_interface": "!lxcbr0",
                "p_from_port": hostvars[_g].ansible_port,
                "p_to_host": _g,
                "p_to_port": 22,
            }) }}{%
        endfor %}{{
        _r
    }}'
  vars:
    _guests: '{{
        hostvars
        | dictselectattr("location", "eq", inventory_hostname)
        | list
    }}'
```

Here I prepare data for the following tasks that will add corresponding `iptables` rules. Is there a way to make it any more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*in my opinion:*

I think part of your problem is the line noise intermixed with the actual "meat" of the problem; contrast that with something like:

```
_forwards: |
   {%- set r = [] -%}
   {%- for g in guests %}{%
     set _ = r.append({
       "p_from_interface": "!lxcbr0",
       "p_from_port": hostvars[g].ansible_port,
       "p_to_host": g,
       "p_to_port": 22,
     })
   %}{% endfor -%}
   {{ r }}
```

I also wanted to point out that jinja vars are block scoped, so you don't need to prefix them with underscores to keep them from "leaking" out of your jinja template; `r` and `g` will not be available anywhere else.

Comment: To add to this, I still think that `{{ r.append(...) }}` is better than `{% set _ = r.append(...) %}`.

Comment: Actually in this particular case `{%-` and `-%}` are not needed. Ansible templates are rendered with [`trim_blocks`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#whitespace-control). It'd be necessary if there were spaces before tags.